# Uma tabela apenas para armazenar imagens ou dividir por tipos?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Quero fazer um cadastro de usuários, onde eles devem colocar sua foto de perfil e dentro do programa, armazenar outras imagens, é melhor eu fazer uma tabela só para todas as fotos ou dividir pra cada tipo?

Eu vi alguns lugares falando que é melhor fazer uma só tabela pra tudo, mas sem dar muito um porquê disso!

Comment: Se você tem um conjunto de imagens, inclusive a foto de perfil, relacionadas ao mesmo usuário você tem que verificar se em seu projeto existe alguma justificativa para necessitar separar a foto de perfil das demais imagens. Em termos de banco de dados não há por que separar.

Comment: @anonimo entendi, em termos do projeto não tem uma justificativa, o que eu estava pensando era se separar iria ajudar na eficiência do banco e etc. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!! Acho que não teria problema em fazer tudo junto mesmo!

Comment: Otimização precoce é a mãe de todos os males. Faça seu projeto e implemente-o. Se durante os testes verificar que existe um problema de desempenho então estude as queries mais utilizadas e avalie se algum tipo de divisão de tabelas pode otimizá-las.

Comment: @ArthurOliveira A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta forma pode ser interessante em boa parte dos casos **como otimização**. Em geral você precisa dos dados do usuário em vários contextos mas não a foto, então pode ser que tendo só os dados consiga ler vários deles em um único acesso ao meio de armazenamento que costuma ser bem lento. Se tiver tudo junto é provável que cada usuário provoque pelo menos um acesso, mesmo que não pegue a(s) foto(s).

Mas estou especulando, pode ser que o PostgreSQL tenha uma otimização que não cause esse efeito, aí não vejo muita vantagem. Na verdade sem conhecer a real implementação atual do PostgreSQL não dá para garantir nada, tudo pode acontecer, por isso precisa sempre testar.

Seria possível por exemplo que um acesso ao usuário fosse cacheado na memória com foto por estar junto, e ocupando mais espaço na memória poderia afetar a performance geral por ter menos dados cacheados. Duvido que isto aconteça de fato, mas é uma possibilidade.

Pode ser que o PostgreSQL tenha uma motivação específica, alguns sistemas de banco de dados até são ruins para por imagens dentro dele. Com uma referência para o local que afirmou isto poderia ajudar dar uma resposta mais precisa.

Do ponto de vista conceitual não tem problema por tudo junto, por otimização pode ser bem interessante separar.

Comment: Minha dúvida é o seguinte, eu tenho uma tabela de usuários, e esses usuários vão adicionar 1 foto de perfil, no momento do cadastro, e durante a utilização do sistema, eles poderiam adicionar outras fotos, por exemplo, imagem de comida. A foto de perfil somente iria aparecer no perfil dele, praticamente, e as fotos de comida, seriam divulgadas em uma página comum onde outras pessoas teriam acesso. Eu queria saber se é uma boa prática separar esses dois tipos de imagem (perfil e comida, por exemplo), ou se posso somente fazer uma tabela para todas imagens.

Comment: Eu respondi o motivo de usar uma coisa ou outra, dizer o que é melhor para você não é algo que respondemos aqui, porque nunca temos informações suficientes para isto. Motivações ensinam alguma coisa, dizer o que fazer, não. Pesquise sobre boa prática aqui no site, especialmente o que eu falo sobre. Esquece esse negócio de boa prática, isso não resolve problema específico de ninguém.

Comment: Sim, com certeza, e você realmente respondeu o que eu queria, os motivos de usar um ou outro, já me ajudou muito, e com certeza me motivou a estudar mais sobre. O que eu acho é que talvez, se ficasse separado por tipos, a tabela não ficaria tão cheia, e assim a busca seria mais rápida, mas acho que a quantidade de dados pra isso fazer algum efeito teria que ser muito grande.

Comment: Isso só testando, adequadamente.